# error MSB3103: Invalid Resx file in MSBuild

Tags: c#, docker, msbuild

Hi I am trying to build my c# project by using MSBuild. Here is error log:

```
C:\my-project\myproject_Workstation\myproject\myproject.Config\Properties\Resources.resx : error MSB3103: Invalid Resx file. Type  in the data at line 123, position 5, cannot be loaded because it threw the following exception during construction: The specified module could not be found [C:\my-project\myproject_Workstation\myproject\myproject.Config\myproject.Config.csproj]
  C:\my-project\myproject_Workstation\myproject\myproject.Config\Properties\Resources.resx : error : TargetInvocationException: Type  in the data at line 123, position 5, cannot be loaded because it threw the following exception during construction: The specified module could not be found [C:\my-project\myproject_Workstation\myproject\myproject.Config\myproject.Config.csproj]
C:\my-project\myproject_Workstation\myproject\myproject.Config\Properties\Resources.resx : error :    at System.Resources.ResXResourceReader.ParseXml(XmlTextReader reader) [C:\my-project\myproject_Workstation\myproject\myproject.Config\myproject.Config.csproj]
C:\my-project\myproject_Workstation\myproject\myproject.Config\Properties\Resources.resx : error :    at System.Resources.ResXResourceReader.EnsureResData() [C:\my-project\myproject_Workstation\myproject\myproject.Config\myproject.Config.csproj]
C:\my-project\myproject_Workstation\myproject\myproject.Config\Properties\Resources.resx : error :    at System.Resources.ResXResourceReader.GetEnumerator() [C:\my-project\myproject_Workstation\myproject\myproject.Config\myproject.Config.csproj]
C:\my-project\myproject_Workstation\myproject\myproject.Config\Properties\Resources.resx : error :    at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ProcessResourceFiles.ReadResources(ReaderInfo readerInfo, IResourceReader reader, String fileName) [C:\my-project\myproject_Workstation\myproject\myproject.Config\myproject.Config.csproj]
C:\my-project\myproject_Workstation\myproject\myproject.Config\Properties\Resources.resx : error :    at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ProcessResourceFiles.ReadResources(String filename, Boolean shouldUseSourcePath, String outFileOrDir) [C:\my-project\myproject_Workstation\myproject\myproject.Config\myproject.Config.csproj]
C:\my-project\myproject_Workstation\myproject\myproject.Config\Properties\Resources.resx : error :    at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ProcessResourceFiles.ProcessFile(String inFile, String outFileOrDir) [C:\my-project\myproject_Workstation\myproject\myproject.Config\myproject.Config.csproj]
C:\my-project\myproject_Workstation\myproject\myproject.Config\Properties\Resources.resx : error : XmlException: Type  in the data at line 123, position 5, cannot be loaded because it threw the following exception during construction: The specified module could not be found Line 123, position 5. [C:\my-project\myproject_Workstation\myproject\myproject.Config\myproject.Config.csproj]
C:\my-project\myproject_Workstation\myproject\myproject.Config\Properties\Resources.resx : error :  [C:\my-project\myproject_Workstation\myproject\myproject.Config\myproject.Config.csproj]
C:\my-project\myproject_Workstation\myproject\myproject.Config\Properties\Resources.resx : error : Win32Exception: The specified module could not be found [C:\my-project\myproject_Workstation\myproject\myproject.Config\myproject.Config.csproj]
C:\my-project\myproject_Workstation\myproject\myproject.Config\Properties\Resources.resx : error :    at System.Drawing.Icon.Initialize(Int32 width, Int32 height) [C:\my-project\myproject_Workstation\myproject\myproject.Config\myproject.Config.csproj]
C:\my-project\myproject_Workstation\myproject\myproject.Config\Properties\Resources.resx : error :  [C:\my-project\myproject_Workstation\myproject\myproject.Config\myproject.Config.csproj]
```

This process is I run inside docker. What I was missing? I can build this project inside the local computer. What could be the possible issue? Thanks.

Update

This is resx file from line 121 to 123

```
<data name="config_icon" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">
    <value>..\Resources\config_icon.ico;System.Drawing.Icon, System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a</value>
  </data>
```

This icon file also exists inside the resources folder.

Comment: How does your dockerfile look like? `System.Windows.Forms` is windows specific dll, it can be a reason of error

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski, I was use this image : `FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:3.5-windowsservercore-ltsc2019`

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski, I also try with : `FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019` . My project target framework is 4.6.1.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I add a picture into the source and changed the path in the image:
[image: Try change picture source]